# Implement a Cellular Automaton ? "Rule 110"

Tags: c, arrays, cellular-automata, automaton

I was wondering how to use the Rule 110, with 55 lines and 14 cells. I have to then display that in an LED matrix display.

Anyway my question is, how can I implement such automaton ??

I dont really know where to start, can someone please shed some light on how can I approach this problem ?

Is there a specific METHOD I must follow ?

Thanks

--PROGRAM USED IS -> C

*EDIT*

```
char array[54][14];
for(v=0;v<55;v++){ 
  for(b=0;b<15;b++){ 
    if(org[v][b-1]==0 && org[v][b]==0 && org[v][b+1] == 0)                                                         
      {
        array[v][b]=0;
      }
      array[v][b]=org[v][b];
 }

}
```

Does that make sense ?? org stands for original

Comment: I added the "hpomewrk" tag; if I'm wrong, let us know.

Comment: Ok I deleted my other topic :)

Comment: Now you're getting into the right neighborhood.  Two things: (1) you've got the rule step where all three cells are 0 -- but there are seven more rules, for 001 through 111.  So you'll need a total of eight if's. (2) think about the effect of that last assignment,      array[v][b]=org[v][b]; -- it doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, every cellular automaton is built around a "recurrance relation", so that the state at time *t* depends on the state at time *t-1*.  So every cellular automaton has a basic structure where you have some data structure, like an array, that represents the state.  So, abstractly, your program will look like

```
State t
/* initialize t */
while(/* end condition isn't satisfied */){
    t = rule(t);
    /* display state somehow */
}
```

where `rule(t)` is a function that computes that next state.

The next step is to come up with a data structure to represent the state.  That's actually easy -- the state of an elementary 1 d cellular automaton is just a vector of 1s and 0s.

So you need an array of 14 small numbers.  Space is not going to be an issue, so use int:

```
 int t[14] ; /* state vector*/
```

The end condition is easy -- you're supposed to do 55 rows, so you need

```
 int count = 0;
 while(count++ < 55)
```

Notice that gives you rows 0-54, which is 55.  A good basic pattern in C is that you start at 0, post-increment, and test less-than.  Probably 9 out of 10 loops you write in C will have that pattern.

Now, finally, the question is how to implement your rule.  Unfortunately, since this is C, you can't do it quite as simply as in my description; the rule has to update the vector in place.  That's going to look a lot like

```
void rule(int t[]){
     /* compute the update here */
}
```

Now, I'm not going to tell you exactly how to compute the update, because then you don't get any of the fun.  But you might find the Wikipedia article on [Rule 110 interesting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_110).

When you read it, ponder this: This simple rule is "Turing complete" -- which means its capable, perhaps with lots of fussing about, of representing *any* computation.  That simple rule, in itself, is a "computer" in the theoretical sense.

**Update**

Okay, a little more on the rules.  Have a look at the rule table in the Wiki article.  What it shows is that you take three cells of your array and determine the next value for the middle one of the three.

So in your rule, you need the array you pass in, *t*, and an array for the next instant, call it *t1*.

```
  void rule(int t[]){ // there's the original
       int t1[14];    // there's the new array
       int ix ;       // an index for the loop that's coming up
```

You want to go through each cell of the array

```
       for(ix=0; ix < 14; ix++){
```

and check the cell, along with the cells to left and right

```
            if(t[ix-1] == 0 && t[ix] == 0 && t[ix+1] == 0)
               t1[ix] = 0;
            else if(t[ix-1] == 0 && t[ix] == 0 && t[ix+1] == 1)
               t1[ix] = 1;
```

and so on.  You'll need to think about what happens at the edges, ie, when `ix == 0` or `ix == 13`.

Fincally, you'll need another `for` loop to copy `t1` back into `t`.

Comment: Hmm, can I replace these conditions with if statements ? For example, if I put : If array [0][0]=1, [0][1]=1, [0][2]=1, then [1][1]=0 ... or does this make no sense ?

Comment: You're on the right track, but this is a one-dimensional array, so the left hand side will always be t[something] = something ;

Comment: Thank you, very informative !! If I get stuck later on ill post back here :)

Comment: Thank you for the update, so since I got columns as well, I must add another value, for example : t1[14][col] ... right ?

Comment: Yes.  If you're going to display them all at once, you need a second dimension, as you've shown it.